# am I able to change a varable within a method in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a game, but I have run into a roadblock I cannot figure out. this is the part of my code that I am failing to understand

```
from random import randint
apple = (0, 0)
def placeApple():
    apple = (randint(0, 19), randint(0, 19))
    fillCell(apple[0] * 20, apple[1] * 20, appleColor)
print(apple)
```

I feel like this should change apple to a point with a random integer 0 through 19 but when I call print(apple) in the console I always get (0, 0)

Comment: you are declaring a global variable `apple`, so when you print it, you will get the value you are clearly defining.

Comment: You need to research about scope

Comment: You are never calling the function.

Comment: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python

Comment: -> Call the function in the first place
-> After choose between returning a value and assigning it back to apple, or add `global` before `apple in the function scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can you can declare `global apple` (not recommended):

```
def placeApple():
    global apple
    apple = (randint(0, 19), randint(0, 19))
    fillCell(apple[0] * 20, apple[1] * 20, appleColor)
```

Or `return` it:

```
def placeApple():
    apple = (randint(0, 19), randint(0, 19))
    fillCell(apple[0] * 20, apple[1] * 20, appleColor)
    return apple
```

But for either of these you actually have to call the function, e.g. for the `return` option:

```
apple = placeApple()
print(apple)
```

Comment: If you are going to vote down, please provide feedback.

Comment: I definitely agree. I can bet somebody who marked this question as duplicated downvoted us.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that you have a global variable called `apple`, and inside your function you have a local variable also called `apple`. If you want to modify a global variable inside your function you should use `global`:

```
def placeApple():
    global apple
    apple = (randint(0, 19), randint(0, 19))
    fillCell(apple[0] * 20, apple[1] * 20, appleColor)

placeApple()

print(apple)
```

However, changing global variables inside functions is a very bad practice since it could cause you a headache when you have to debug. With this approach, `apple` will be updated every time you call `placeApple`.

Comment: You are still never calling the function.

Comment: @FanJ, what do you mean?